# WooCommerce: Get categories and products by vendor (on vendor page)

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, categories, product

I try to list all the Products of the Vendor on the Product Vendor Site well sorted in the Categories they are in. (Don´t know why they don´t do it by default...).

> ```
> Category A
>    • Subcategory A 
>      - Product 1
>      - Product 2
>
> Category B
>    • Subcategory B
>      - Product 10
> ```

Different things doesn´t work right.

1. It doesn´t hide the empty categories
2. It´s not sorting the Category by manual order
3. How to integrate subcategories?

Actually I also find really rare Documentations on that.
Any Ideas on that?

I'm using the product vendor plugin.
The vendor page is located under this url:
http://example.com/vendor/myfirstvendor/

```
<?php

global $wp_query;
$term = $wp_query->queried_object;

$args_cat = array(
    'number'     => "",
    'orderby'    => "menu_order",
    'order'      => 'ASC',
    'hide_empty' => true,
    'parent'     => '',
    'include'    => $ids
);

$product_categories = get_terms( 'product_cat', $args_cat );

$count = count($product_categories);

    foreach ( $product_categories as $product_category ) {

        echo '<h2>' . $product_category->name . '</h2>'; ?>

        <?php woocommerce_product_loop_start(); ?>
        <?php woocommerce_product_subcategories();
 ?>

        <?php
        $args = array(
            "post_type"             => "product",
            "posts_per_page"        => 1000,
            "product_cat"           => $product_category->name,
            "wcpv_product_vendors"  => $term->slug,
            "orderby"               => "ASC" );
        $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
        while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); global $product; ?>

                <?php wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' ); ?>

        <?php endwhile; ?>

        <?php woocommerce_product_loop_end(); ?>

    <?php } ?>
```

Comment: Questions: 1) Are you using an additional plugin as a woocommerce vendors plugin? If yes which ones? 2) Could you include some of your pertinent searched references links and the link to source of your code. (updating your question) Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38842054/woocommerce-subcategory-custom-page I have created a new question here....kindly reply here